# using in the Typesafe config file contents

Tags: scala, config, typesafe, typesafe-config

As far as I know `#` in typesafe config is used to comment things. 
Is there a way to escape it and use it a values? Say I want to have a parameter with value:

```
DB_PASSWORD=Yo,10#
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's what quotes are for:

```
DB_PASSWORD="Yo,10#"
```